# Сохранение артефактов gitlab job с разными условиями(when)

Tags: gitlab-ci

Есть джоба, которая сохраняет аретфакты только при падении джобы:

```
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - '**/foo'
      - '**/bar'
    when: on_failure
```

Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы артефакт `foo` сохранялся только при `on_failure`, а артефакт `bar` - всегда (`always`)

В [доке](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactswhen) gitlab таких примеров не нашел